# How predators plan to get hosts for their hunt?

Tags: alien-vs.-predator

In Alien vs Predator (2004) we learn that the Predators use the pyramid as a training ground/arena, where they hunt and breed xenomorphs. Fair enough.

When the predators are coming to the temple at the beginning of the movie what was their plan to acquire new aliens to hunt?

Xenomorphs need hosts to develop from facehugger to runner. **So what did the Predators plan to use as hosts?**

Comment: Repeat after me: Predators and Aliens never met in any movie. That was just a fleeting nightmare.

Comment: Predators and Aliens never met in any movie. *Repeated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that one of the main characters said that the termal (heat) signal detected with the satellite was supposed to lure them there. That means that the predators orbiting the Earth must have a good understanding of the culture and psychology of Earth inhabitants. That is the only in-universe explanation given in the movie.

> Wealthy industrialist Charles Bishop Weyland discovers through thermal imaging that there is a pyramid buried 2000ft beneath the ice. [...] The explorers deduce that this is why the current Predators are at the pyramid, and that the heat bloom was to attract humans for the purpose of making new Aliens to hunt.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_vs._Predator_(film))

We learn in the movie that in ancients times people would volunteer to be hosts:

> Through translation of the pyramid's hieroglyphs the explorers learn that the Predators have been visiting Earth for thousands of years. It was they who taught early human civilizations how to build pyramids, and were worshiped as gods. Every 100 years they would visit Earth to take part in a rite of passage in which several humans would sacrifice themselves as hosts for the Aliens, creating the "ultimate prey" for the Predators to hunt.

Although this is the movie in-universe explanation:

1- It seems that not much in the movie is consistent with the comic franchise.

2- Even if the predators come every 100 years, it doesn't explain well what happened to the people living at the whaling station (Probably forced or lured into hosts as well, since no bodies were found), or how the predators managed to find hosts the time before that. Since the pyramid must have been covered in ice for centuries, it could be really difficult for predators to be able to systematically lure or get hosts for the xenomorphs every 100 years. So I think that there is just some plot-inconsistency with this host-gathering method due to bad writing.

Comment: There's no inconsistency. Like the film *Predators*, the Predators probably just kidnapped people and forced them to become hosts until humans re-inhabited the island with the British whaling station. Luring people in to become hosts became an acceptable practice again with the arrival of the British, and the increase in human technological development.

Comment: @JamesSheridan, maybe. There is no evidence in the movie. Nevertheless they were considered gods millennia ago. I just I don't know if the comic series explain more... Maybe as humankind advanced they were forced to change their "status" from god-like and receive volunteer hosts to have to kidnap them without being noticed and drag them to the island.

Comment: Agreed - the comic storyline made much more sense, with the Predators seeding facehuggers on planets and in areas which they KNEW would result in hosts for the aliens.